# Replacing light and fan switches in a trailer bathroom

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, trailer

I am attempting to replace the light and fan switch in my bathroom.

When I pulled them out the type of switches they are is confusing me.  It appears that there are 2 wires going into the switch on the right, then jumped over to the next switch, then 2 wires going out.

Am I to pigtail the two wires going into the first switch and then pigtail the 2 wires going out of the second switch?

Also, how would i jump the 2 switches together, and would I have to jump all (black,white, and ground), or just the hot?

Will the switch I have work?

[image]
[image]
[image]